# Javascript object properties shared across instances?

Tags: javascript, oop, reference

I have an example class that has two properties: a variable and an object:

```
var Animal, a, b;

Animal = (function() {
  function Animal() {}

  Animal.prototype.priceb = 4;

  Animal.prototype.price = {
    test: 4
  };

  Animal.prototype.increasePrice = function() {
    this.price.test++;
    return this.priceb++;
  };

  return Animal;

})();

a = new Animal();

console.log(a.price.test, a.priceb); // 4,4
b = new Animal();
console.log(b.price.test, b.priceb); // 4,4
b.increasePrice();
console.log(b.price.test, b.priceb); // 5,5
console.log(a.price.test, a.priceb); // 5,4 !! not what I would expect. Why not 4,4?
```

For some reason, this seems to have a weird behavior. It looks like the class stores a reference to the object, so that it is shared across multiple instances.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 7):

The object (reference) that's in the prototype is indeed shared across the instances, until such time as the reference itself is modified, as opposed to the *contents* of the object.

The way around it is to give each object its own `.price` property within the constructor:

```
function Animal() {
    this.price = { test: 4 };
}
```

The (default) primitive value you've supplied in `Animal.prototype.priceb` is *also* initially shared across instances, except that as soon as you modify it the instance acquires its own copy that shadows the original value from the prototype.

Comment: `"!? the instance acquires its own copy !?"` - ONLY if the property is not OBJECT (passed as reference)

Comment: @bortunac even if the property is a reference to an object.  If you have `Animal.prototype.obj = {}` and then overwrite `obj` in an _instance_ then that instance now has its own reference to a new object.

Comment: @Alnitak ... yes your right ... i just want to impose a usual mistake `o1= new  Animal;o2=new Animal;o1.obj.prop1=1;`now `o2.obj.prop1 ===1 ;`